# Issue on Running jQuery on Chrome Extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am trying to develop a simple cheome extension but I am not able to set the jQuery to work with it:

Here is my file Structure:

--root
         -- manifest.json
         -- popup.html
         -- script.js
         -- js
                -- jQuery.js
                -- clip.js

Here is the Code which I have in `manifest.json`

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "My ext",
  "description": "This is a Development.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "https://secure.flickr.com/"
  ],

  "content_scripts": [
    {
    "all_frames": false,
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "exclude_matches": [],
      "css": [
        "css/content/page.css"
      ],
      "js": [
        "js/jquery.js",
        "js/clip.js"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and popup.html as:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My app</title>
    <style>body {min-width: 357px;overflow-x: hidden;} </style>
    <!--
      - JavaScript and HTML must be in separate files: see our Content Security
      - Policy documentation[1] for details and explanation.
      -
      - [1]: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html
     -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <table style="width:300px">
<tr>
  <td id="fname">Jill</td>
  <td>Smith</td> 
  <td>50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Eve</td>
  <td>Jackson</td> 
  <td>94</td>
</tr>
</table>
  </body>
</html>
```

and finally script.js as:

```
$( "#fname" ).on( "click", function() {
  alert( "HI");
});
```

I also trired to run both jQuery through `<head>` by calling jQuery from cdn and declaring a document ready JavaScript at the page but it didn't work either.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My app</title>
    <style>body {min-width: 357px;overflow-x: hidden;} </style>
    <!--
      - JavaScript and HTML must be in separate files: see our Content Security
      - Policy documentation[1] for details and explanation.
      -
      - [1]: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html
     -->
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
     $( "#fname" ).on( "click", function() {
       alert( "HI");
      });
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <table style="width:300px">
<tr>
  <td id="fname">Jill</td>
  <td>Smith</td> 
  <td>50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Eve</td>
  <td>Jackson</td> 
  <td>94</td>
</tr>
</table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be several issues with your setup.

You might want to read into Content Scripts as they don't seem to do what you think they do. Content scripts are when you are injecting into another site's page. It is not your page. You are actually inserting the jquery file into their page.
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html

> **Content Scripts**
>
> Content scripts are JavaScript files that run in the context of web pages. By using the standard Document Object Model (DOM), they can read details of the web pages the browser visits, or make changes to

Also, you can not run inline javascript without setting your security policy:
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#JSExecution

> **Inline JavaScript will not be executed**
>
> Inline JavaScript will not be executed. This restriction bans both inline  blocks and inline event handlers (e.g. ).

Have you tried including the jQueryCDN AND your script.js to the head of your HTML? Like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

You manifest.json should also include the following:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://*.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'"
```

Comment: Thanks Esteban Felix, it was very helpful but, how about solution? how can I add jquery to extension?

Comment: @user3162145 I updated my answer, you almost had it! You just needed to combine both of the approaches!

Comment: yeah actually at last code sample on the post I added the code into <head> but jquery not functioning thete!

Comment: I mean it is OK on loading for example if I want to alert a message on load it works but not working on a code like this: $( "#test" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).addClass( "hover" );
  }, function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "hover" );
  }
);

Comment: Instead of using Google's jquery CDN, it may be easier to use the jquery.js file you're already including in the extension.